# C++ unordered map to store command line parameters

Tags: c++, unordered-map, argv, c-strings

I am developing a command line program using unordered_map and char* in C++.

However, it does not work.

Here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <unordered_map>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  std::unordered_map <char*, char*> hash;

  for (int i = 1; i<argc; i++){
   if (argv[i][0] == '-'){
     hash[argv[i]] = argv[i+1];
   }
 }

 if (hash["-file"]){
   printf("Openning the file %s \n", hash["-file"]);
 }else{      
   printf("Error open files \n" );
   return 0;
 }
```

}

When I provide my arguement lists:

```
myprogram.exe -file "c:\myfile.txt" -option1 .....
```

It can not open the input file.

Can anybody help me with it?

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm going to just tell you now the `char*` you're passing as your *lookup* key is *not* the same actual address residing as the key in your map used as the *insertion* key. One is from `argv[]`, the other a read-only literal. In *most* cases, pointers are **not** what you want for keys. (there are situations where it is useful, but this isn't one of them, obviously). john briefly had it up here, and it may be coming as an answer; use `std::string` as the key type for your map.

Answer (score 1):

As @WhozCraig said in a comment, you need to use `std::string` instead of `char*` as the key type in your map.  You can keep using char* as the value type, since `argv` has the lifetime of the entire program.

However, if you can use Boost, their Program Options library is better than any of this hand-written stuff.  Unfortunately since you appear to be using Windows, your platform doesn't provide any built-in stuff like `getopt_long()`, but Boost PO is the best facility for this in C++ anyway.